# Laravel 4 how to listen to a model event?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to have an event listener binding with a model event `updating`.
For instance, after a post is updated, there's an alert notifying the updated post title, how to write an event listener to have the notifying (with the post title value passing to the listener?

Comment: I presume you've read through the documentation about [Events](http://four.laravel.com/docs/events)?

Comment: yes,what I'm not sure is what name should use? In a custom event,we can use `Event:fire('event_name',array('value'))`,and then `Event:listen('event_name',function($param1){..})` So should I use `Event:fire('project::updating',array($project->title))` ?

Comment: I tried Event:listen('event_name',function($param1) with Model events and they didn't seem to be working. Wish this was a bit clearer in the documentation! I would assume this would also have worked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The documentation briefly mentions [Model Events](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events).  They've all got a helper function on the model so you don't need to know how they're constructed.

> Eloquent models fire several events, allowing you to hook into various points in the model's lifecycle using the following methods: creating, created, updating, updated, saving, saved, deleting, deleted. If false is returned from the creating, updating, saving or deleting events, the action will be cancelled.

---

```php
Project::creating(function($project) { }); // *
Project::created(function($project) { });
Project::updating(function($project) { }); // *
Project::updated(function($project) { });
Project::saving(function($project) { });  // *
Project::saved(function($project) { });
Project::deleting(function($project) { }); // *
Project::deleted(function($project) { });
```

*If you return `false` from the functions marked `*` then they will cancel the operation.*

---

For more detail, you can look through [Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php) and you will find all the events in there, look for uses of `static::registerModelEvent` and `$this->fireModelEvent`.

Events on Eloquent models are structured as `eloquent.{$event}: {$class}` and pass the model instance as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks!I will have `Post::updating(function($post) {....$post->title.... }); ` to accomplish the notification.

Answer (score 37):

This post:
http://driesvints.com/blog/using-laravel-4-model-events/

Shows you how to set up event listeners using the "boot()" static function inside the model:

```
class Post extends eloquent {
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function($post)
        {
            $post->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
            $post->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
        });

        static::updating(function($post)
        {
            $post->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
        });
    }
}
```

The list of events that @phill-sparks shared in his answer can be applied to individual modules.

Comment: Very convenient way to automate a bit the model. Thanks.

Comment: Nice! Way more convenient than to throw out ten thousand service providers just to register these...

Answer (score 7):

I got stuck on this because I assumed subscribing to default model events like Event:listen('user.created',function($user) would have worked (as I said in a comment). So far I've seen these options work in the example of the default model user created event:

```
//This will work in general, but not in the start.php file
User::created(function($user).... 
//this will work in the start.php file
Event::listen('eloquent.created: User', function($user)....
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! I use event subscribers to keep my classes slim.

Answer (score 0):

```
Event::listen('eloquent.created: ModelName', function(ModelName $model)   {
    //...
})
```