# Mysql listening to events

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I am a beginner in the laravel framework for php. I just had a question, its a general mysql question. I tried looking online but I couldn't find help. My main question is,

why do people listen for query events? What does it even do? What does it even mean in the first place? As I came across the laravel function

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time)
```

and I don't know what it does because I just don't understand the concept of listening event.

Answer (score 0):

This is called database event  listening.For listening to the query event and output sql queries in laravel.

We use:

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time)
{
    //
});
```

See about the [event models](http://four.laravel.com/docs/events) here and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757616/laravel-4-how-to-listen-to-a-model-event) too